# Flatten List in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a LINQ query which returns `IEnumerable<List<int>>` but i want to return only `List<int>` so i want to merge all my record in my `IEnumerable<List<int>>` to only one array.

Example :

```
IEnumerable<List<int>> iList = from number in
    (from no in Method() select no) select number;
```

I want to take all my result `IEnumerable<List<int>>` to only one `List<int>`

Hence, from source arrays:
`[1,2,3,4]` and `[5,6,7]`

I want only one array
`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`

Thanks

Answer (score 731, accepted):

Try [`SelectMany()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx)

```
var result = iList.SelectMany( i => i );
```

Comment: Thanks, I always forget this one -- I know it's there, but I just spend way too much time Googling for it every time I need to use it.  Bookmarking this answer. :-)

Comment: For a while I was afraid that I was the only one who ever needed this. Thanks Mike!

Comment: Is there some alternate syntax for `SelectMany( i => i )` ? I've seen this syntax used a lot but it seems a degenerate use of the select feature, so I would have expected the language designers to come up with a shortcut syntax specifically for lists of lists

Comment: @Andy argh! If only the language designers had given us some way to 'extend' an `IEnumerable` ourselves!

Answer (score 93):

With query syntax:

```
var values =
from inner in outer
from value in inner
select value;
```

Comment: Thanks exact syntax I was looking for, and so many SO answers list something else more verbose.

Comment: This is much, much better than SelectMany. More clear exactly what's going on IMO, thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Personally I always find the query syntax version much less intuitive than the method calling version. When Resharper offers to convert loops to LINQ expressions if it gives me the query syntax I always go for undo.

Comment: Pretty funny how divided "the community" is on this - to me this is completely unreadable, though I do realize it's habit with the arrow function syntax and that this is a valid solution.

Answer (score 26):

```
iList.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray()
```

Comment: @recursive What did everyone else miss? `.ToArray()`? -- That's kind of circumstantial -- if you only need to iterate once -- or if the items are likely to change, then `.ToArray()` is definitely not what you want.  But with static items that you're going to enumerate multiple times, `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` will give a performance improvement (at the cost of slightly higher memory usage, which, is usually a pretty good deal).

Comment: Presumably the circumstances in this case require arrays, since that was specified in the question.

Comment: @recursive, if we are nitpicking, the OP says that he needs to return `List<int>`, so `.ToList()` would then be the correct choice.

Comment: @MEMark OP also states " to only one array"

Answer (score 15):

If you have a `List<List<int>> k` you can do

```
List<int> flatList= k.SelectMany( v => v).ToList();
```

Answer (score 13):

Like this?

```
var iList = Method().SelectMany(n => n);
```