# How to convert an IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> to a IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, collections, extension-methods

I have an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` collection that I want to convert to a single dimension collection. Is it possible to achieve this with a generic extension method? Right now I'm doing this to achieve it.

```
List<string> filteredCombinations = new List<string>();

//For each collection in the combinated results collection
foreach (var combinatedValues in combinatedResults)
{
    List<string> subCombinations = new List<string>();
    //For each value in the combination collection
    foreach (var value in combinatedValues)
    {

        if (value > 0)
        {
            subCombinations.Add(value.ToString());
        }
    }
    if (subCombinations.Count > 0)
    {
       filteredCombinations.Add(String.Join(",",subCombinations.ToArray()));
    }
}
```

If it's not possible to get a generic solution, how can I optimize this in an elegant fashioned way.

Comment: the question in the title is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590723/flatten-list-in-linq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var strings = combinedResults.Select
    (
        c => c.Where(i => i > 0)
        .Select(i => i.ToString())
    ).Where(s => s.Any())
    .Select(s => String.Join(",", s.ToArray());
```

Comment: This whole question has been bizarre! The wording asked one question, the example asked another. And you've answered a third, different question altogether, and got accepted... I've already posted the correct answer, and have no votes (not that I mind, it's just amusing.)

Comment: I think your `Implode` would be more elegant if it just operated on `IEnumerable<string>`. If you want a conversion on each item of some other type of sequence, use `Select` first.

Comment: Your implementation of Implode would probably be more efficient and certainly more concise if it simply used `string.Join` rather than StringBuilder.  i.e. `return string.Join(separator,sequence.ToArray())`

Comment: @Eamon: Having done a bit of digging into the String.Join implementation, I think you are dead right. Fixed.

Answer (score 18):

You can use the [Enumerable.SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) extension method for this.

If I read your code correctly, the code for that would be:

```
var filteredCombinations = combinatedResults.SelectMany(o => o)
    .Where(value => value > 0)
    .Select(v => v.ToString());
```

**Edit**: As commented, the above code is not joining each element of the subsets to a string, as the original code does. Using the built-in methods, you can do that using:

```
var filteredCombinations = combinatedResults
     .Where(resultSet => resultSet.Any(value => value > 0)
     .Select(resultSet => String.Join(",",
         resultSet.Where(value => value > 0)
                  .Select(v => v.ToString()).ToArray()));
```

Comment: What if you want every subset to be one element of the new collection? That's what I do with the String.Join...

Comment: @Earwicker, I fail to see how I will get empty strings in the result. The resultSet must start out as an enumerable of a numeric type, since the elements is being compared to zero in the orignal code. (I admit I typed the code without Visual Studio, so feel free to correct me :-)

Comment: There are two `if` statements in the original code. You only have one `Where` clause. You've kept the one that filters out the zero values, but you have missed the one that filters out empty sub-lists. A list containing all zeros will become an empty array, which you pass to `Join`. The original code doesn't do that.

Comment: Hmm, now you're querying every `resultSet` twice with the same expression. Sorry to be picky... you could just copy my answer to save time! :)

Answer (score 3):

I would personally use [Enumerable.SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx), as [suggested by driis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240346/how-to-convert-an-ienumerableienumerablet-to-a-ienumerablet/2240356#2240356).

However, if you wanted to implement this yourself, it would be much cleaner to do:

```
IEnumerable<T> MakeSingleEnumerable<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> combinatedResults)
{
    foreach (var combinatedValues in combinatedResults) {
         foreach (var value in combinatedValues)
              yield return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You asked two different questions. The one you described in the title is already answered by drilis.

But your example code is a different problem. We can refactor it in stages. Step 1, build the `subCombinations` list using some Linq:

```
List<string> filteredCombinations = new List<string>();

//For each collection in the combinated results collection
foreach (var combinatedValues in combinatedResults)
{
    var subCombinations = combinatedValues.Where(v => v > 0)
                                          .Select(v => v.ToString())
                                          .ToList();

    if (subCombinations.Count > 0)
       filteredCombinations.Add(string.Join(",",subCombinations.ToArray()));
}
```

Now the outer loop, leaving us with just this:

```
var filteredCombinations = combinatedResults
    .Select(values => values.Where(v => v > 0)
                            .Select(v => v.ToString())
                            .ToArray())
    .Where(a => a.Count > 0)
    .Select(a => string.Join(",", a));
```

Answer (score 0):

use linq [SelectMany](http://team.interknowlogy.com/blogs/danhanan/archive/2008/10/10/use-linq-s-selectmany-method-to-quot-flatten-quot-collections.aspx)