# Reports VS 2010, drill down ICollection

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, reporting

I have the following Linq, its linked to a report.

Resuming it's a report of bills, but bills have multiple products, so i have an `ICollection` of `Products`. The idea is to show each bill with their multiple `Products` in a single report using drilldown (trying to avoid subreports).

```
public class BillsDataSet
{
    public int IDGestion { get; set; }
    public string Comentario { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BillProduct> Products { get; set; }
    public decimal Monto { get; set; }
    public string Personal { get; set; }

    public static List<BillsDataSet> BillsPorFecha(DateTime dtFechaInicial, DateTime dtFechaFinal)
    {
        Context db = new Context();

        List<BillsDataSet> BillsDataSet = (from p in db.Bill
                                               select new BillsDataSet()
                                               {
                                                   IDGestion = p.IDBill,
                                                   Comentario = p.Historial.FirstOrDefault().Comentario,
                                                   Products = p.BillProduct,
                                                   Monto = p.Total,
                                                   Personal = p.Historial.FirstOrDefault().CodigoEmpleado
                                               }).ToList();
        return BillsDataSet;
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error on the web page report...
[image: I'm getting this error on the web page report]

What I want to achieve is to have a drilldown on `Products` to hide/show all the `Products` related to the bill...

Comment: This is probably because of lazy loading `Products`.

Comment: you should take a look to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637818/handle-this-object-datasource-on-reporting-services

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
public static List<BillsDataSet> BillsPorFecha(DateTime dtFechaInicial, DateTime dtFechaFinal)
{
    Context db = new Context();

    List<BillsDataSet> BillsDataSet = (from p in db.Bill
                                           select new BillsDataSet()
                                           {
                                               IDGestion = p.IDBill,
                                               Comentario = p.Historial.FirstOrDefault().Comentario,
                                               Products = (from b in db.BillProduct where b.product_id == p.IDBill select new BillProduct()).ToList() as ICollection<BillProduct>,
                                               Monto = p.Total,
                                               Personal = p.Historial.FirstOrDefault().CodigoEmpleado
                                           }).ToList();
    return BillsDataSet;
```

}