# How to merge array inside another array of it

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have an array which has another array inside of it and I want to merge all of them into one array using linq.

[image]

Comment: So what have you tried and what's your question?

Answer (score 1):

You want to flatten your multidimensional array, use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx):

```
var mergedValues = values.SelectMany(subArray => subArray)
                         .ToArray();
```

you can see other examples of flattening different structures [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590723/flatten-list-in-linq)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx):

```
var flattened = a.SelectMany(row => row).ToArray();
```