# How to get a list of Ints via a LINQ statement?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following class

```
public class PaymentItemViewModel
    {
        public List<int> Placements { get; set; }

        public int StandardPayment { get; set; }

    }
```

Then a function returns the following

```
IEnumerable<PaymentItemViewModel> paymentItems
```

How can I get a list of all the Placements Ids, using LINQ?

Can i do something like the following?

```
List<int> placementIds = paymentItems.Any(x=>x.Placements) ??
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you are looking for [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) method

```
List<int> placementIds = paymentItems.SelectMany(vm => vm.Placements).ToList()
```

Comment: thanks... just for my knowledge using LINQ, as opposed to using loops to get the placementIds, is there a performance difference?

Comment: It seems that in this case SelectMany would be about 10 times slower than version with AddRange and 3 times slower than nested foreach

Comment: @hazzik a bit shocking. care to conjecture why ? are you sure it's not some sort of cache issue in your test rig?  my guess: it has to do with the informalness of SelectMany, SelectMany has to infer a lot of stuf before beginning it's trip down the creating the results lane.  When you say foreach, you are giving some serious intelligence to the process, that it is known that this traversal method will reach all depths necessary.

Comment: @AndyzSmith I think it SelectMany just slower in general as proportions stay the same with different numbers of items. Of course I can not always use nested foreach/foreach+AddRange, for example in lazy computations.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
var placementIds = new List<int>();

foreach(var item in paymentItems)
{
    foreach(var placementId in item.Placements)
    {
        placementIds.Add(placementId);
    }
}
```

If you really want to do it in LINQ, then you can do this:

```
var placementIds = paymentItems.SelectMany(item => item.Placements).ToList();
```

Comment: Since it's a `List` you could get rid of one `foreach` loop by using AddRange, right?

Answer (score 2):

This should work.  Any() just sees if any exist, and takes a boolean.  [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) grabs all of a property or object "and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence".

```
List<int> placementIds = paymentItems.SelectMany(x=>x.Placements).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

`from aPaymentModelView in PaymentItems

from aPlacements in aPaymentmodelView

select aPlacements`

this should work according to this

[Flatten List in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590723/flatten-list-in-linq)

EDIT

nicely provided by hazzik

`var ids1 = (from model in models
from placement in model.Placements
select placement).ToList();`

i guess i don't understand how it knows to concatenate the `List<int>` s

if i select placement, and then ToList, i should get a `List<List<int>>`

EDIT 2 
ok, so actaully the cross join

`from aModel in Models
from aPlacement in aModel.Placements`

produces a tuple of { Model, Placements }
but these tuples are **implicity concatenated** with each other and all you have to do is to exclude the outer label, the Model

EDIT 3 i suppose it cannot be considered a cross join, although it feels like one, but since the placements are already segregated into separate lists, it is really just a full breadth and depth tree traversal,

Which could only be accurately described by a M-soft-ism, *SelectMany*

i am getting this idea from the type reported by ToString for the var.  It has type of SelectMany iterator.