# LINQ query isn't applying order by

Tags: c#, linq

Here is my quite simple linq query in C#

```
var latest = (from calc in context.db_accounts_last_contacts
    group calc by calc.account_id into calcGroup
    select calcGroup);

var ordered = (from calcg in latest
    let item = (from items in calcg
        orderby items.last_contact_date descending
        select items).FirstOrDefault()
    select item);
```

Here is what db_accounts_last_contacts has
[image]

So basically my query should return this
[0] should be row id 13 (because last_contact_date order in my ordered query)
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aByEm.png) should be row id 2
[2] should be row id 14

Basically this does work however every time I run my ordered query I will always pull out row ID 2 when I should be pulling out row ID 13,

Can anyone see why my orderby isn't being used in my ordered linq query?

Update

This is my linq query now

```
var ordered = (from calcg in latest
    let item = (from items in calcg
        select items).FirstOrDefault()
    orderby item.last_contact_date descending
    select item);
```

But I am still getting the same results

Answer (score 3):

In this bit of code:

```
var ordered = (from calcg in latest
    let item = (from items in calcg
        orderby items.last_contact_date descending
        select items).FirstOrDefault()
    select item);
```

Your `OrderBy` is being applied before a `.FirstOrDefault()`, and one item is returned.  I understand why that `OrderBy` is there; it dictates which item is selected.  But that's not going to produce a final ordering; if you want the final set to be ordered, you need another `OrderBy` outside of the `let`.

Comment: Seems like you're looking more for a Flatten.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590723/flatten-list-in-linq.  Alternatively, you can try creating an `unordered` set, and then just `orderby` and `select` from that.

Comment: I don't want the return type to be db_accounts_last_contacts

Comment: Use `select` `new` and it can be any type you want.

Comment: It would seem I need to order my groupby not order the whole query