# flatten a list in linq using c#

Tags: c#, linq, list

I used linq to create a list of IO_EQUATIONS. An IO_EQUATION consists of a single OUTPUT_POINT and a List of INPUT_POINT. INPUT_POINT and OUTPUT_POINT have a common x, y, and z coordinate but they contain other fields that are not common. I want to flatten out the List of IO_EQUATIONS to either an anonymous type or a specific point type (x, y, and z only) so that I see the Output followed by all the inputs for each IO_EQUATION in a list.

I was able to use linq to list all the OUTPUT_POINTS using the following code. list41 is the list of IO_EQUATIONS

```
var flat = (from d2 in list41
            select (new BINARY_IO()
              {
                 propX = d2.propOutputPoint.propX,
                 propY = d2.propOutputPoint.propY,
                 propZ = d2.propOutputPoint.propZ,
                 propDir = POINT_DIRECTION_Types.Output,
              })).ToList();
```

I was able to use linq to list all the INPUT_POINTS using the following code.
list41 is the list of IO_EQUATIONS. propIOPointList is my list of INPUT_POINT

```
var flat = (from d2 in list41
            from d3 in d2.propIOPointList
            select (new BINARY_IO()
                 {
                    propX = d3.propX,
                    propY = d3.propY,
                    propZ = d3.propZ,
                    propDir = POINT_DIRECTION_Types.Input,
                 })).ToList();
```

I can get the information separately by I want the data to be formatted as an output followed by the inputs, then the next output followed by the inputs, etc.

I have a feeling this is really simple and I just can't get it to work.

Thanks

Comment: can we see the declarations of each class involved please (IO_EQUATIONS, INPUT_POINT, OUTPUT_POINT, others?), so I can improve my answer

Comment: Rather than a paragraph explaining your model, the model's code would be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To flatten a list of list in LINQ, use `.SelectMany`

```
var flattenedList = list1.SelectMany(i => i.PropertyThatIsAList)
```

Many similar questions, for example :
[Flatten List in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590723/flatten-list-in-linq)

Comment: This answer is pretty incomplete. Can you show him how to rewrite his example with query syntax that uses `SelectMany`?

Comment: I've tried SelectMany on my List of INPUT_POINT and that works fine but it doesn't include my OUTPUT_POINT in the final list. It feels like I want to select the OUTPUT_POINT and concatenate the list of INPUT_POINT to create the final list I'm looking for.

Comment: Would it be something like: `list41.SelectMany(eq => eq.INPUT_POINTs, (eq, inputs) => new { OUTPUT = eq.OUTPUT_POINT, INPUTS = inputs).ToList()`

Comment: You could further modify it with a `Select`: `list41.SelectMany(eq => eq.INPUT_POINTs, (eq, inputs) => new { EQ = eq, INPUT = inputs).Select(t => new { OutputPoint = t.OUTPUT, InputX = t.INPUT.X, InputY = t.INPUT.Y, InputZ = t.INPUT.Z).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to transform each item in `list41` into an `IEnumerable<BINARY_IO>` in the order you listed, then using `SelectMany` to flatten the resulting `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<BINARY_IO>>`.

```
var flat =
    (from d2 in list41
     select
        Enumerable.Repeat(
            new BINARY_IO {
                propX = d2.propOutputPoint.propX,
                propY = d2.propOutputPoint.propY,
                propZ = d2.propOutputPoint.propZ,
                propDir = POINT_DIRECTION_Types.Output}, 1)
            .Concat(
                from d3 in d2.propIOPointList
                select new BINARY_IO {
                    propX = d3.propX,
                    propY = d3.propY,
                    propZ = d3.propZ,
                    propDir = POINT_DIRECTION_Types.Input}))
    .SelectMany(i => i)
    .ToList();
```

Note that I use `Enumerable.Repeat(v, 1)` to get a singleton, there are other methods as well.

Additionally you could inline the call to `SelectMany` but at that point you might want to switch away from query syntax and just use a manual call to `Select` for the second `from`/`select`.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Listing the single output followed by concatenating the list of inputs was exactly what I was trying to do.