# Searching a List of List

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following object:

```
List<List<MyObj>> lst;
```

I need to find a list of all the objects (List< MyObj >) in the inner list, that has ID equal 1.

I tried:

```
lst.Where(x => x.FindAll(y=> y.ID== "1"));

lst.FindAll(x => x.FindAll(y=> y.ID== "1"));
```

and also tried to use `Any()` but no luck.

Comment: What is the desired output? The lists with the `MyObj` or the objects themselves?

Comment: You need to find the matching MyObj objects or the lists that contain them? Or you even need to filter those lists?

Comment: Get a list of the objects

Comment: @PlexisPlexis: so `List<MyObj> desiredResult`?

Comment: What *exactly* should be the format of desired output ??? Is it `List<List<MyObj>>` or `List<MyObj>` ?

Comment: I mentioned in the question; "I need to find a list of all the objects in the inner list, that has ID equal 1"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flatten List in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590723/flatten-list-in-linq)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`SelectMany()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads) to flatten the lists and then filter the elements:

```
var result = lst.SelectMany(x => x).Where(y => y.ID == "1").ToList();
```

Comment: or `lst.SelectMany(x => x.Where(y => y.ID == "1")).ToList()`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I don't think there is a huge difference, except that your variation creates much more enumerators than mine.

Comment: I doubt there is a performance difference. It might be more readable or understandable for some.

Answer (score 4):

```
List<MyObj> list1 = lst.SelectMany(x => x.Where(y=> y.ID== "1")).ToList();
```

or

```
List<List<MyObj>> list2 = lst.Where(x => x.Any(y=> y.ID== "1")).ToList();
```

depending on what it is you want as a result..

Answer (score 2):

[SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany) is your friend. Example:

```
var listOfListsOfStrings = new List<List<string>>();

listOfListsOfStrings.Add(new List<string>() {"a", "b"});
listOfListsOfStrings.Add(new List<string>() {"c", "d"});

var allStrings = listOfListsOfStrings.SelectMany(s => s);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", allStrings.ToArray())); //prints: a, b, c, d
```

So in your case you just need:

```
lst.SelectMany(x => x).Where(y => y.ID == "1")
```

Comment: @GiladGreen There is no need in writing 'captain obvious' comments

Answer (score 1):

Let me add another option to the already good set of options. It is using `Hashset<T>` for search, by converting the internal `List<T>`, this would help when data size is more, since `Hashset<T>` has O(1) search instead of O(N) for `List<T>`

```
List<List<MyObj>> lst;

var result = lst.where(x => 
             {
               // Assuming ID to be string type
               var hashset = new Hashset<string>(x.Select(y => y.ID));
               return hashset.Contains("1");
              }
           );
```

In case you are not keen to do conversion, then following code would do:

```
var result = lst.where(x => x.Any(y => y.ID == "1"));
```

`result` will be of type `List<List<MyObj>>`, which will be filtered, currently we are are supplying `Func<T,bool>` to the `Enumerable.Where`, when data is supplied at run-time, then its easier to construct `Expression<Func<T,bool>>`, which gets compiled at run-time into correct `Func<T,bool>` delegate to filter actual list