# select just the child collection in linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
   List<ContractType> filteredContractTypes = contractTypes.Where(x => x.ContractTypeName == "SUA").ToList();
   List<ContractSubType> contractSubTypes = filteredContractTypes.Select(c => c.ContractSubTypes).ToList();
```

the class contract type has a collection of subcontracttypes. how can I select just the subcontracttypes in linq?

I am getting the below error

```
> Cannot implicitly convert type 
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Models.ContractSubType>>'
> to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Models.ContractSubType>'
```

Comment: Try this contractTypes.Where(x => x.ContractTypeName == "SUA").SelectMany(c => c.ContractSubTypes).ToList()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `(2D List)` But `contractSubTypes` is a 1D List!
You can use `var` and then you realize your mistake.

```
var contractSubTypes = filteredContractTypes.Select(c => c.ContractSubTypes).ToList();
```

or you can use [SelectMany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590723/flatten-list-in-linq) to `Flatten List in LINQ`!